# transitionFromView with UIViewAnimationOptions similar like navigating with UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewanimation

I'm using a similar approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25109353/426227) for the animation from one view controller to another:

```
UIWindow *window = (UIWindow *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows firstObject];
[UIView transitionFromView:window.rootViewController.view
                    toView:vc.view
                  duration:0.65f
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve // transition animation
                completion:^(BOOL finished){
                    window.rootViewController = vc;
                }];
```

Looking into the [UIViewAnimationOptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIViewAnimationOptions) I didn't found an option for the default animation, which occurs when doing the same with `UINavigationController`.

Is it possible to get the same animation behavior (moving the view left)? How?

I tried it with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13047259/426227) animation:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.65 animations:^{
    view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-view.frame.size.width, 0);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    // do something
}];
```

but while translating to the new view the background is completely black instead of bringing the other view controller in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I'm doing it in a different way. I start with my navigation controller and its root view. Then I push another view controller on the stack. In `viewDidAppear` of this new view controller I'm removing the first view controller from the navigation stack. One downside: You can see the back button for a short time.

The animation solution I tried will need the other view controller animated in. Also I had problems with views which very not layout correctly (because of `edgesForExtendedLayout`).